# Is there an equivalent to RxJs<=4#ofArrayChanges in RxJs5

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am using Angular2 and I want to track changes in array,but there is only RxJs5,and seems it hasn`t such functionality.

Comment: Well, if you're interested MobX has excellent interoperability with Rx (I use them together all the time) and it gives you the same sort of change tracking observables - it's super fast too. I'm not sure if I'd use it with Angular 2 though.

Comment: With Angular2 you'd use rxjs directly or via Ngrx, although the MobX / ngrx etc topic is hardly related to the question IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent. The `Object.observe` proposal has been [withdrawn from ES7](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe), so there is little point in having `ofArrayChanges` or `ofObjectChanges` in RxJS 5.

Comment: It's actually very easy to recreate with Proxies.