# Using RxJS To Track Changes In An Object?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there a way to use RxJS to track changes in a particular object? Based on my research, there used to be a method called Observable.ofObjectChanges() to create an observable that tracks object changes, but it looks like that has been deprecated.

I've experimented with using Object.from and Object.of but neither seem to trigger when a particular object is updated.

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide more context about the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: do you want to keep a change history? do you only want to listen to changes? You need to add more detail about your use-case

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sure - I'm working within Angular 2 to populate a template that is data-bound to a property of the parent object of my component.  When this object changes, due to changes at the parent level, I want to detect that change in Typescript in the child component so I can perform some related functions. I was hoping to be able to use the Observable.subscribe method to catch these updates but I'm just running into a wall.  Thanks for any guidance or insight you can provide.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam I am only looking to detect changes to the property.

Comment: Could you [edit] to give a [mcve]? Why doesn't regular `@Input` data binding work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks again for your help. The actual code I'm working in is very complicated and would be difficult to reproduce here.  I'll see if I can come up with a slimmed-down version of it.  I was just hoping someone else had already come across a way of using RxJS to capture changes to an object, given that it appears RxJS could do it in the past.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39181621/6680611

Comment: @ChicagoMike Why do your child components require more than one change detection? I think usually it's the reverse order, of a child component prop changing and a parent component prop needing a second change detection. Please help me understand this scenario. Is there a workaround based on your store object structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a BehaviourSubject with an Observable and listen to the Observable.

```
private _aStringArry: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

public aStringArray: Observable<string[]> = this._aStringArry.asObservable();

setStringArray(stringArray: string[]): void {
    this._aStringArry.next(stringArray);
}
```

Subscribe to aStringArray for changes. I suggest this as in some cases BehaviorSubjects would throw Promise rejections unless wrapped in Observables.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a custom setter for the property you want to monitor, that notifies an RxJS BehaviorSubject, and then you subscribe to that subject to listen for changes.

Something like this:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

class MyClass
{
   changesSubject : BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject();

   _myprop : any;

   public set myprop(val : any) {
       this.changesSubject.next(val);
       this._myprop = val;
   }
}

let myobj = new MyClass();
myobj.changesSubject.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
myobj.myprop = "this should trigger a change detection";
```